# How to avoid a destructor being called twice in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm testing out a class representing an dynamic array data structure I made for myself as practice with the language, but I ran into a problem where the destructor is called twice over, causing a heap corruption error.

So far, I have attempted to comment out some of the delete words. However, this leads to undefined behavior.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"
#include <vector>

template<typename T> class Spider {
private:

    T** pointer;

    int maxSize;
    int lengthFilled;
public:
    //default constructor
    Spider()
    {
        pointer = new T * [1];
        maxSize = 1;
        lengthFilled = 0;
    }
    //destructor
    ~Spider()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lengthFilled; i++)
        {
            pop();
        }
        delete[] pointer;
    }
    //Pushes an object in
    void push(T thing)
    {
        if (lengthFilled == maxSize)
        {
            increaseSize();
        }

        T* thinggummy = &thing;

        //then save its pointer in the functional array
        pointer[lengthFilled] = thinggummy;
        lengthFilled++;
    }

    //pops the array
    void pop()
    {
        delete pointer[lengthFilled-1];
        setSize(lengthFilled - 1);
        lengthFilled--;
    }
}

int main()
{

    Spider<Spider<int>> test((long long)1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        test.push(Spider<int>());
        test.get(i).push(2);//this is implemented in the actual code, just omitted here
        std::cout << test.get(i).get(0);
        std::cout << "push complete\n";
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

The expected results for this program should be:

```
2
push complete
2
push complete
```

Press any key to continue...

Instead, I get an critical error code in the debug log of "Critical error detected c0000374".

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - No, not that one. A wrong duplicate is worse than a just duplicate remaining wrongfully open

Comment: @StoryTeller Basically it answers the OP's question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - It doesn't. The OP is taking the address of a local and storing it. They haven't hit the rule of 3 yet.

Comment: `T* thinggummy = &thing` . You are taking address of a stack variable and will be gone as soon as your `push` will complete its execution. And there might happen a *kaboom!!* as soon as you'll dereference `thinggummy`

Comment: @WhiteSword - You should post answers in the (now reopened) answer section.

Comment: @XnossisX How is your code even compiling? I suppose you've tried to provide the minimalist code, with syntax and other errors, right?

Comment: Yes, I provided the version of the code that was the only part necessary for finding the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. Like WhiteSword already mentioned, you are taking the address of a local variable when you do `T *thinggummy = &thing`. That is going to cause trouble since that address will be invalid as soon as you leave scope (unless maybe `T` resolves to a reference type).
2. You call `delete` on the things in the `pointer` array. However, these were not allocated via `new`. Instead they are just addresses of something. So you are trying to free something that was never allocted.

Comment: Thanks! Would I need to create a new T in the heap, and then deep copy the contents of thing over?

Comment: What to do depends on what type `T` actually is and/or for which types this `Spider` class should work. For example, if `T` is a primitive type then there is no need to allocate/deallocate anything. If `T` is a pointer then maybe it is ok to just store the pointer, maybe you want a deep copy. In general you probably want to rely on the copy constructor and assignment operators of `T` to do the right thing. You may want to check some template tutorials/courses. These sort of things are usually explained in depth there.